# Cognito "Alias entry already exists for a different username"

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have the following Cognito code to create users:

```py
import boto3
import os
import logging

session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=os.environ.get('AWS_AK'),
    aws_secret_access_key=os.environ.get('AWS_SK'),
    region_name=os.environ.get('AWS_REGION')
)

client = session.client('cognito-idp')


def register_user(username, password, email):
    response = client.admin_create_user(
        UserPoolId=os.environ.get('COGNITO_POOL_ID'),
        Username=username,
        TemporaryPassword=password,
        UserAttributes=[
            {
                'Name': 'email',
                'Value': email
            },
        ],
    )
    return response
```

For some reason, when I create the first user everything is ok, but once I create the second one (with the 3 completely different variables) it says the following:

```json
{"__type":"InvalidParameterException","message":"Alias entry already exists for a different username"}
```

The usernames are different, the emails and the password too.

Even when I manually create a user in the console, with completely random data, I also get this error:
[AWS Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jzv24.png)

I tried everything. Even creating new User Pool.

Comment: Try to add `ForceAliasCreation=False` in `client.admin_create_user`

Comment: I also tried with that and it gives me another error:
"User account already exists" It is impossible for the user to already exist.